# unable to find explicit android.widged.VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview, assets

i have error like this, why?

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.erjp.widget.VideoView} have you declared this activitiy in your androidManifest.xml?
```

i have declared my class name `"VideoActivity"` in `androidManifest.xml` but why error like this?
can anybody help?

```
<activity
    android:name="MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="VideoActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
</activity>
```

And thi is my class code: 
package com.erjp;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoActivity extends Activity{
    private final String TAG = VideoActivity.class.getCanonicalName();
    private VideoView videoPlayer;
    private MediaController mediaControler;
    private String pathvideo;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        videoPlayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
        mediaControler = new MediaController(VideoActivity.this);

        pathvideo = MainActivity.DATA_PATH.toString() +"/video/videocpr";
        videoPlayer.setMediaController(mediaControler);
        videoPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(pathvideo));
        videoPlayer.requestFocus();
        videoPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

this is LogCat:

```
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.erjp/android.widget.VideoView}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at com.erjp.MainActivity$ClickVideo.onClick(MainActivity.java:77)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-28 07:48:14.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1999):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are you sure about this post your menifest file code and check that the package names are similar

Comment: i've declared the class in androidManifest, look at above

Comment: No you did not. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

You app crashes because of missing `com.erjp.widged.VideoView`, which most likely is referenced in `VideoActivity`'s layout. Isn't it a type there as proper spelling is `widget` not `widged` so most likely your package is correct but reference is not.

Comment: its true `android.widget.VideoView`, there is no ERROR about widget